# What is earliest date when I can apply for a renewal of my US visa stamp on my passport?

Tags: usa, visa, immigration

I am an in the USA on an O1 visa.

The dates on my I1797 mention validity till February 2026. However, the O1 visa stamp on my passport is valid till December 2024.

What is the earliest date when I can book an appointment in my home country for renewal of the O1 visa stamp on my passport? Can I book a visa appointment in March 2024 if it is available?

Comment: When you get a new visa, they cancel the old one.  There's nothing stopping you from doing it a week after you receive the first visa.  Note also that you can replace the visa after it expires, as long as you can be sure that your first trip out of the US after expiration will be long enough for you to replace the visa during that trip.  You can also avoid replacing it entirely if you are certain that you will not leave the US between its expiration and the end of your O-1 status.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I book a visa appointment in March 2024 if it is available?

Yes. March 2024 is now. You could have booked it in December, too. There's no "waiting" period that would require you to hold off applying to a new visa once the old one expires.

Visa validity is not based on the I797 alone, but also on various other factors like reciprocity with your country of citizenship. So it may be for shorter duration than the I797.